# Why does my enemy attack after it is dead?(Javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
     function battle(){
    //User turn
    alert("It's your turn!");
    var user_move = prompt("Type 1 to use fireball, 2 to use lightning strike, or 3 to do earthquake");
    if(user_move == 1){
      var r = Math.round(Math.random()*(dmg.length-1));
      alert("You did "+dmg[r]+" damage to the enemy!");
      enemy_HP = enemy_HP - dmg[r];
    }
    else if(user_move == 2){
      var r = Math.round(Math.random()*(dmg.length-1));
      alert("You did "+dmg[r]+" damage to the enemy!");
      enemy_HP = enemy_HP - dmg[r];
    }
    else if(user_move == 3){
      var r = Math.round(Math.random()*(dmg.length-1));
      alert("You did "+dmg[r]+" damage to the enemy!");
      enemy_HP = enemy_HP - dmg[r];
    }
    alert("Your enemy has "+enemy_HP+"HP");
    //Enemy turn
    alert("Now its your enemys turn!");
    var a = Math.round(Math.random(enemy_attack.length-1));
    var r = Math.round(Math.random()*(dmg.length-1));
    alert("You enemy used "+enemy_attack[a]+"\nand did "+enemy_dmg[r]+" damage to you!");
    HP = HP - enemy_dmg[r];
    alert("You now have "+HP+"HP!");
    //If still living keep battling
    if(HP > 0 && enemy_HP > 0){
      battle();
    }
    else if(HP <= 0){
      alert("You lost D:");
    }
    else if(enemy_HP <= 0){
      alert("You win :D!");
    }
  }
  battle();
```

I am trying to make a fun little js battle game but sometimes when you kill the enemy it has one final attack and can kill you even when it is dead. How do I fix it?

Comment: You need to specify a scenario where your problem is reproducible. People may not be able to help you, if you ask for a solution without specifying the precise problem. Could you provide a workflow in which your problem is reproducible?

Comment: Is the game "the walking dead"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your enemy attack code inside of an if statement

```
if (enemy_HP > 0){
   //enemy attack code
} else alert("You win :D!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, judging by your code you first do the enemy damage and only then check if he has enough life. Include damage dealing from enemy inside if statement where you check if enemy is dead or not.